# Auto correct city and state names

Tags: google-places-api, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have a list of city and associated state names in MySQL.Is there any way to auto correct all those city and state names which are wrong,as some were entered manually insted of using the google places autocomplete feature.
I am using Node.js in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Google Maps API doesn't have that feature yet - my suggestion is to input those addresses that aren't correct into Google Place Autocomplete again. Then update your database with the correct address.

For more info about Google Place Autocomplete, please check **[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)** link.

To learn more about Google Maps APIs, please check **[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/)**.

You can also file a Feature Request through this **[link](https://issuetracker.google.com/)**.

Hope it helps!